# Stopping, restarting and changing variables in a thread from the main program (Python 3.5)

Tags: multithreading, oop, tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

I'm very new to threading am and still trying to get my head around how to code most of it. I am trying to make what is effectively a text editor-type input box and so, like every text editor I know, I need a cursor-bar thing to indicate the location at which the text is being typed to. Thus I also want to be able to flicker/blink the cursor, which i thought would also prove good practice for threading.

I have a class cursor that creates a rectangle on the canvas based on the bounding box of my canvas text, but I then need to change it's location as more characters are typed; stop the thread and instantaneously hide the cursor rectangle when the user clicks outside of the input box; and lastly restart the thread/a loop within the thread (once again, sharing a variable) - the idea here being that the cursor blinks 250 times and after then, disappears (though not necessary, I thought it would make a good learning exercise).

So assuming that I have captured the events needed to trigger these, what would be the best way to go about them? I have some code, but I really don't think it will work, and just keeps getting messier. My idea being that the blinking method itself was the thread. Would it be better to make the whole class a thread instead? Please don't feel restricted by the ideas in my code and feel free to improve it. I don't think that the stopping is working correctly because every time I alt+tab out of the window (which i have programmed to disengage from the input box) the Python shell and tkinter GUI stop responding.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading, time

class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, parent, xy):
        self.parent = parent
        #xy is a tuple of 4 integers based on a text object's .bbox()
        coords = [xy[2]] + list(xy[1:])
        self.obj = self.parent.create_rectangle(coords)
        self.parent.itemconfig(self.obj, state='hidden')

    def blink(self):
        blinks = 0
        while not self.stop blinks <= 250:
            self.parent.itemconfig(self.obj, state='normal')
            for i in range(8):
                time.sleep(0.1)
                if self.stop: break
            self.parent.itemconfig(self.obj, state='hidden')
            time.sleep(0.2)
            blinks += 1
        self.parent.itemconfig(self.obj, state='hidden')

    def startThread(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.blinking = threading.Thread(target=self.blink, args=[])
        self.blinking.start()

    def stopThread(self):
        self.stop = True
        self.blinking.join()

    def adjustPos(self, xy):
        #I am not overly sure if this will work because of the thread...
        coords = [xy[2]] + list(xy[1:])
        self.parent.coords(self.obj, coords)

#Below this comment, I have extracted relevant parts of classes to global
#and therefore, it may not be completely syntactically correct nor
#specifically how I initially wrote the code.
def keyPress(e):
    text = canvas.itemcget(textObj, text)
    if focused:
        if '\\x' not in repr(e.char) and len(e.char)>0:
            text += e.char
        elif e.keysym == 'BackSpace':
            text = text[:-1]
    canvas.itemconfig(textObj, text=text)
    cursor.adjustPos(canvas.bbox(textObj))

def toggle(e):
    if cursor.blinking.isAlive(): #<< I'm not sure if that is right?
        cursor.stopThread()
    else:
        cursor.startThread()

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=400, borderwidth=0, hightlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    textObj = canvas.create_text(50, 50, text='', anchor=NW)
    root.bind('<Key>', keyPress)
    cursor = Cursor(canvas, canvas.bbox(textObj))
    #Using left-click event to toggle thread start and stop
    root.bind('<ButtonPress-1', toggle)
    #Using right-click event to somehow restart thread or set blinks=0
    #root.bind('<ButtonPress-3', cursor.dosomething_butimnotsurewhat)
    root.mainloop()
```

If there is a better way to do something written above, please also tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: you don't need threading to blink a canvas item. Are you specifically looking for a treaded solution? tkinter isn't thread-safe, so a threaded solution is much, much more complex than a non-threaded solution.

Comment: Could you please post an Asher to show how you would do it without using threading and still keeping a constant time loop?  I was looking for a threaded solution so that u could build on my experience with threading but I would appreciate any solution that would not disrupt the flow of a program if the input box were imported into a larger project (which it will be).